# How do I update the meta-data of a directory using aws s3 cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am attempting to use the following command in a bash script to update the x-amz-meta-uid and x-amz-meta-gid of files and folders recursively.

`aws s3 cp s3://$SOURCE_CLOUD_BUCKET_PATH s3://$DESTINATION_CLOUD_BUCKET_PATH --recursive --quiet --metadata-directive "REPLACE" --metadata "uid=$USER_UID,gid=$USER_GID"`

However, it only seems to be updating the metadata on files. How can I also get this to update the metadata on the directories/folders also?

`aws --version`

`aws-cli/2.0.43 Python/3.7.3 Linux/5.4.0-1029-aws exe/x86_64.ubuntu.18`

Comment: _WHY_ do you wish to set metadata on a folder? In Amazon S3, you do not need to create folders when storing objects in a given path. The folders magically appear. It is possible to use "Create Folder", which will create a zero-length object with the same name as the folder. When you use tools like s3fs, they are probably storing information against this zero-length object, but it will have **no impact** no the content of the folders. Thus, you might want to revisit _why_ you want to set metadata on the folders themselves (which don't actually exist).

Comment: Thanks for your time @John Rotenstein . I am using S3 to offload uploads media for a number of Wordpress sites. I am using s3fs to mount the s3 bucket as a local filesystem which allows me to simply symlink the uploads folder to the mounted s3. It works great and I have no issues with the current setup. I can set the permissions on files and folders of the mounted s3 perfectly fine using chown, however, this is obviously very slow since s3 is not a real filesystem. I was just hoping there was a more efficient way to set these permissions using aws cli.

Answer (score 1):

As AWS S3 document states : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/using-folders.html

> In Amazon S3, buckets and objects are the primary resources, and
> objects are stored in buckets. Amazon S3 has a flat structure instead
> of a hierarchy like you would see in a file system. However, for the
> sake of organizational simplicity, the Amazon S3 console supports the
> folder concept as a means of grouping objects. Amazon S3 does this by
> using a shared name prefix for objects (that is, objects have names
> that begin with a common string). Object names are also referred to as
> key names.

Since AWS S3 is Object storage service and is not POSIX compliant.

Which means there is no disk level folder structure maintainer.

The folders you are seeing are logical which means a file with name `hello/world.text` will show `hello` as parent folder name while `world.txt` as file name however, the actual filename stored is `hello/world.txt`.

So the meta-data is also managed at file level and not at folder level since, their are no physical folders.

The CLI behaviour is correct and you need to modify meta-data of files. Though, you can modify meta-data of all files / multiple files in a go.

Comment: Thanks Atul. I can change the metadata on folders using a tool like s3 browser or using chown on an s3fs mounted drive, so the meta data seems to be stored on a directory level also. It's just there seems to be no way to manage that via the cli so far as I have been able to find.

Comment: When you are using these tools they are just modifying the metadata of group of files, all files in that folder. As S3 uses logical grouping file names separated by `/`

Answer (score 0):

No need to change the metadata of the files recursively, Metadata of whole folder can be changed. Follow [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/add-object-metadata.html)